# Syntax for declaring more than one serial pins of Arduino mega?

Tags: arduino-mega

How can I declare multiple serial ports for Arduino Mega as it has been in the example below?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(18,19); // RX, TX  //how this syntax can be modified for multiple Rx module?

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
   Serial.write(45);    // send a byte with the value 45

   int bytesSent = Serial.write(â€œhelloâ€); //send the string â€œhelloâ€ and return the length of the string.
}
```

Comment: The Mega has four UARTs. Why are you using `SoftwareSerial`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams..... But how i can access four Softwareserial for Arduino mega?like syntax for single serial port is as,                 SoftwareSerial mySerial(18,19); // RX, TX

Comment: @Code Gorilla    But how i can access four Softwareserial for Arduino mega?like syntax for single serial port is as, SoftwareSerial mySerial(18,19); // RX, TX – Hafeez Ahmad Fii Zue 2 mins ago    edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the built in serial ports then just user the other objects that are pre-declared as per:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin

Answer (score 5):

From the [official docs on serial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial):

> The Arduino Mega has three additional serial ports: Serial1 on pins 19 (RX) and 18 (TX), Serial2 on pins 17 (RX) and 16 (TX), Serial3 on pins 15 (RX) and 14 (TX).

Which means, you use `Serial1` for serial on pins 19 and 18 instead of `Serial`:

```cpp
void setup(){
   Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
   Serial1.write(45);    // send a byte with the value 45

   int bytesSent = Serial1.write("hello"); //send the string "hello" and return the length of the string.
}
```

Comment: what will be the syntax for serial two and three if it is "SoftwareSerial mySerial(18,19)" for serial 1

Comment: Isn't is obvious? Did you read the quoted text?

Comment: how can we access more than two Softwareserial?

Comment: Why do you need software serials if you have 4 hardware serials?

Comment: can i share you the complete code so that you can amend it easily?  i need yours email id?